# Getting Issue while connecting Facebook API in Maui App

Tags: facebook, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, maui

1. [https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri_uri}&scope=public_profile,pages_manage_posts](https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri_uri%7D&scope=public_profile,pages_manage_posts)

I got the code from this request.

2. Now Putting that code in

[https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/oauth/access_token?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={secret_id}&code=](https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri%7D&client_secret=%7Bsecret_id%7D&code=)

I got the access_token

3. [https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name&access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name&access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

I got the user_id and name

but when I post the request with some file for upload in [https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{user_id}/photos?access_token=](https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/%7Buser_id%7D/photos?access_token=)

It shows
"error": {
"message": "(#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permission publish_actions is deprecated",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200,
"fbtrace_id": "A-sDKV8AZcq0hyONFkzq53C"
}

Comment: Where is the code that generates the error?

Comment: I think that the redirect url should be the url of your application that Facebook will use when Facebook has validated the login.